# UWP Bind CurrentStateChanged of VisualStateGroup to ViewModel

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp

I am trying to convert the Master/Detail Sample from Microsoft to MVVM. (Sample: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlMasterDetail)

In the Sample, the CurrentStateChanged Event is bound to some Code behind function

MainPage.xaml

```
<VisualStateGroup x:Name="AdaptiveStates" CurrentStateChanged="AdaptiveStates_CurrentStateChanged">
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
private void AdaptiveStates_CurrentStateChanged(object sender, VisualStateChangedEventArgs e)
```

How do I bind that to an View Model?

When i try to bind it to a Property like this:

MainPage.xaml

```
<VisualStateGroup x:Name="AdaptiveStates" CurrentStateChanged="{Binding AdaptiveStates_OnCurrentStateChanged}">
```

MainPageViewModel.cs

```
public ICommand AdaptiveStates_OnCurrentStateChanged
{
   get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}
```

The DataContext is set in the Code behind file.

I get following Compile Error:

> \Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Common.targets(263,5): Xaml Internal Error error WMC9999: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Which does not really tells me any Information on whats wrong. Anyone got any Ideas why this error appears or how I could accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my Solution with x:Bind.

Step one: Declare ViewModel as Property in Code behind

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public MainPageViewModel MainPageViewModel { get; set; }
```

Step two: Change method return type of AdaptiveStates_OnCurrentStateChanged to expected VisualStateChangedEventHandler

MainPageViewModel.cs

```
public VisualStateChangedEventHandler AdaptiveStates_OnCurrentStateChanged
```

Step Three: Bind the Function with x:Bind

MainPage.xaml

```
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="AdaptiveStates" CurrentStateChanged="{x:Bind MainPageViewModel.AdaptiveStatesOnCurrentStateChanged}">
```

I probably spent too much time figuring that out. I hope that this at least will help someone else who is stuck with the same problem.